# Using Circe optics to modify all fields of an object, or all items of an array

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am trying to modify a nested JSON structure using [Circe's optics](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html). However, all the examples are only modifying a single field within the object with the known name.

What I need to do:

- Assuming `foo` key of my object contains an array of objects, increment the `counter` key in each of those.
- Assuming `bar` key of my object contains an object, increment the `counter` key in values mapped to each key in that object.
- Keep all the other values in the object intact.

Example:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "counter": 1
    },
    {
      "counter": 2
    }
  ],
  "bar": {
    "three": {
      "counter": 3
    },
    "four": {
      "counter": 4
    }
  }
}
```

should become

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "counter": 2
    },
    {
      "counter": 3
    }
  ],
  "bar": {
    "three": {
      "counter": 4
    },
    "four": {
      "counter": 5
    }
  }
}
```

The behavior when the types of the object and its members are not what I expect is not important.

I expect something like this:

```scala
val incrementCounterArray: Json => Json =
    root.foo.eachArrayItem.counter.modify(_ + 1)
val incrementCounterObject: Json => Json =
    root.bar.eachObjectValue.counter.modify(_ + 1)
```

but I don't see any definitions for what would be `eachArrayItem` or `eachObjectValue` in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
val incrementCounterArray: Json => Json =
  root.foo.each.counter.int.modify(_ + 1)

val incrementCounterObject: Json => Json =
  root.bar.each.counter.int.modify(_ + 1)
```

Have a look at the example in the official [circe-optics documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html#modifying-json) for more details: